# Subquery with multiple results, SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a query that looks like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM dbo.document_library_file_attributes 
WHERE my_file_id=
(SELECT my_file_id 
 FROM dbo.document_library_file_attributes 
 WHERE attribute_name='Directory/Key' AND attribute_value LIKE @directory+'%')
```

I want to the subquery to be able to return multiple results, meaning `my_file_id` could equal 'directoryA', 'directoryB', and I want the results for all of these. How would I do that?

Comment: Is my_file_id unique? If so, no need for any joins or subqueries...

Comment: @sgeddes its not unique

Comment: Is `My_File_ID` nullable?

Comment: @GarethD Not nullable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`IN`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms177682.aspx) instead of `=` for result sets:

```
SELECT * 
FROM dbo.document_library_file_attributes 
WHERE my_file_id IN
(SELECT my_file_id 
 FROM dbo.document_library_file_attributes 
 WHERE attribute_name='Directory/Key' AND attribute_value LIKE @directory+'%')
```

It:

> Determines whether a specified value matches any value in a subquery or a list.

Answer (score 3):

I think a `JOIN` is a better way to express what you're trying to do:

```
SELECT DISTINCT lfa2.* 
FROM 
    dbo.document_library_file_attributes lfa
    JOIN dbo.document_library_file_attributes lfa2
        ON lfa.my_file_id = lfa2.my_file_id 
WHERE 
    lfa.attribute_name='Directory/Key' 
    AND lfa.attribute_value LIKE @directory+'%'
```